# Call parametric MySQL view from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, view

I'm trying to build a parametric view in mysql so that I can call it from PHP specifying the parameter.

There are two views actually: the first one which implements the parameter and the second one which just selects from the first:

```
CREATE VIEW first_view AS
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.parameter < get_parameter();

CREATE VIEW second_view AS
SELECT * FROM first_view;
```

The `get_parameter` function is implemented as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_parameter() RETURNS timestamp
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF ISNULL(@parameter) THEN
        RETURN DATE(CURDATE()- INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY);
    ELSE
        RETURN @parameter;
    END IF;
END
```

Then, my query, looks like this:

```
SELECT v.* FROM (select @parameter := '2014-12-31' p) par, first_view v
```

This kind of query allows me to specify the parameter and then select everything from `first_view`.

When I run such query on Mysql Workbench everything works as expected while when i run it via PHP it returns an empty set.

I'm using the same mysql user both on workbench and PHP so it shouldn't be a premission problem.

How can I get the result set with PHP too?

**UPDATE**

I've been trying this on the Mysql CLI client and it returns an empty set as PHP does.

It looks like the query:

```
SELECT v.* FROM (select @parameter := '2014-12-31' p) par, first_view v
```

doesn't actually sets the `@parameter` variable, or at least not the first time.

Infact, if I run the query twice then it works and the view returns what is expected.
I solved the problem by sending two statements from php to mysql:

First I set the parameter:

```
SET @parameter = '2014-12-31';
```

the I run the actual query:

```
SELECT * FROM second_view;
```

Now I wonder: why the first query isn't instantiating the parameter correctly?

Comment: My first guess is, that declaring the get_parameters() function as DETERMINISTIC could be the problem. Did you try it without declaring it as DETERMINISTIC?

Comment: I tried declaring the function NOT DETERMINISTIC and now the query works without setting the variable beforehand. But why does it make the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mysql reference:

> A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same
>   result for the same input parameters

Your function has no input parameters, but considers a variable declared outside of the function.

From mysql reference:

> Declaring a nondeterministic routine as DETERMINISTIC might lead to
>   unexpected results by causing the optimizer to make incorrect
>   execution plan choices.

This is just speculation: But the reason why it works in MySQL workbench and not in CLI/PHP could be that query caching in the workbench session is probably disabled per default.

You could try to verify this disabling the cache during CLI query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE v.* FROM (select @parameter := '2014-12-31' p) par, first_view v
```